# Mac OS connection to Oracle fails with the error ORA-12514

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

So, faced with the issue where I couldn't connect to oracle database using rider on mac os. The strange thing is, that I'm able to connect using datagrip or sqlplus to database, or using windows it also able to connect to database also, but while I'm trying to open the connection in .net it fails with the following exception

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
 ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x000030E2): ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

Connection string in .net application is the same for Windows/Mac machines. Did anyone faced with this already?

Comment: The connection parameters going over the wire are malformed in some way. Either using a mis-spelled service_name value, or submitting SID instead of service_name, or some such.

Comment: @pmdba it can't be, the same connection string copied for both os, but for some reason it fails only in mac os using rider

Comment: the software may be interpreting the connection string differently - like juxtaposing service_name and SID. Check the server side listener logs to determine what is actually getting to the server.

Comment: That's all I've from the logs, the other is stack trace from the code where it was failed, or maybe I missing something?

Comment: the snippet you posted in your question is from the client. you need to check the listener.log file on the database server to see what it *thinks* your client asked for. Compare that to a connection that actually worked.

Comment: you've got a situation where certain clients work fine - so you know there's nothing malfunctioning on the server - and certain clients do not. the error indicates a malformation of the connection parameters that are getting to the server. the listener is expecting a valid `service_name` value and isn't getting one, so double-check how your problem client is configured. make sure you're submitting `service_name` and not `SID`, which is not the same thing.

Comment: shame, that's were user secrets that's override my connection string, it was really incorrect service_name, could please create an answer so I could close this?